# Elastic: How to enable autodetect on metadata like container id in Elastic APM Agent/APM Server?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, docker-compose, apm

I have set up an elastic stack with elasticsearch, filebeat, kibana and apm server, and an spring-boot-application with the apm java agent and started my setup in a docker compose file. I have enabled the dashboard and I can see traces about processes in the application.
But I cannot filter for container id, because there is no id. How do I enable my stack apm server/apm agent to receive the metadata about container id, pod id and so on.

Where can I enable metadata for apm server / apm agent to receive the container id for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I run via docker-compose elasticsearch, apm, kibana and tomcat application in docker.
In apm-*-transaction-* index exist this meta information: `container.id`.
And in apm-*-metrics-* index this information is also stored.
Try to look at json structure at Discover tab by index pattern "apm-*"

```
    {
  "_index": "apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "EyeudHEBxv4GJJ2Qs6yk",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "container": {
      "id": "100b5f0e673337f4381533d8ae9ab47ababf271e422c26f9ecc278a2aa08e3e7"
    },
    "observer": {
      "hostname": "6940719de3e8",
      "id": "7e715843-6a92-4794-99e3-beadc81cc7bc",
      "ephemeral_id": "a0676d3e-e97f-4179-8b92-88f6214ea035",
      "type": "apm-server",
      "version": "7.6.2",
      "version_major": 7
    },
...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtytQ.png)